# Restrict WebApi endpoint to users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a small PoC WebApi in C#, where a user should be able to view or edit his full name, e.g.:

- GET `my.api.com/users` would return all users (array of JSON objects containing `Id` and `FullName` properties, representing users). This is accessible by everyone.
- GET `my.api.com/users/{id}` would return a single user matching that `id`. This is accessible by everyone.
- PUT `my.api.com/users/{id}` for editing the `FullName` property of the user matching that `id`. This should only be accessible on a per-user basis.

I would like to make my `PUT` request require authentication, and each user only being able to edit his own `FullName` (e.g. user with id `0` should not be able to make a `PUT` request to `my.api.com/users/1`)

Coming from an ASP.NET MVC world, I'm slightly confused as to how to approach this. In MVC, I would simply mark the action as `[Authorize]` and ensure that the ID of the user making the call matches the actual ID passed in that particular action.

I've understood how authorization would work in WebApi using [this Microsoft resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) (e.g. using bearer tokens, etc). Would that imply that user registration would be very similar to ASP.NET MVC, i.e. registering using a username/password and then authenticating against the WebApi using bearer tokens?

Comment: Have you considered using the same approach as you'd use for MVC? It should be largely the same (i.e. using `Authorize` and checking the ID). The main difference might be in how you authorize your users, with e.g. bearer tokens, etc.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin, I've updated my answer to include a question about registration. Is my understanding correct? Also, If I was to call a resource using a bearer token, would the token provided be enough for me to assert on the server-side whether the caller calling `my.api.com/users/1` is actually user with ID `1`?

Comment: Yes, one option would be to continue to use the MVC approach for registration, etc. In this case, you could have an additional endpoint for providing credentials and obtaining a token, which you could then pass on to the API. This token could then include [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims), one of which would identify the user (via their ID, etc).

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin :) You mentioned "...to use the MVC approach..." - what would the WebApi approach be? That comment seems to be implying that I'm mixing two different concepts together.

Comment: No, that approach would be fine (I think it's common). Not using the MVC approach might be e.g. using an Angular front-end that uses endpoints for registering users, etc. I was just highlighting that you have options depending on how you intend to consume your Web Api.

Comment: I'll try not to clutter up the comments, but another option would be to use something like [Identity Server](https://identityserver.io/), which is a third-party authority for handling your users and issuing tokens, etc. It's overkill for your PoC, but just worth mentioning.

Comment: thanks @KirkLarkin, very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Authorize]` on WebApi Actions the same way you use it in MVC. Here is a snippet of my old code:

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController
{
    // POST /api/movies/
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.CanManageMovies)]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateMovie(MovieDto movieDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        var movie = Mapper.Map<MovieDto, Movie>(movieDto);
        _context.Movies.Add(movie);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Created(new Uri($"{Request.RequestUri}/{movie.Id}"), movie);
        }

    // PUT /api/movies/1
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.CanManageMovies)]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateMovie(int id, MovieDto movieDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        var movieInDb = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

        if (movieInDb == null)
            return NotFound();

        Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieInDb);

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();

    }

    // DELETE /api/movies/1
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.CanManageMovies)]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteMovie(int id)
    {
        var movieInDb = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

        if (movieInDb == null)
                return NotFound();

        _context.Movies.Remove(movieInDb);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using the `[Authorize]` annotation to limit the Actions only to logged in users who are allowed to manage movies.

Comment: thanks @BoškoBezik - how are you handling actual registration/authentication on the API? Is it similar to the approach I mention in my question?

Comment: @globetrotter My apologies but I didn't see that you've updated your question. This is an old project which did not have any particular registration system. I added users in a very crude way by manually adding them with the `Register(RegisterViewModel model)` method in `AccountController`.